# Show tooltip on mouseover of a disabled dropdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, onmouseover

```
 countLabel() == 0 ? $('#' + uniqueValueee + 'AndOrSelection').prop("disabled", true) : $('#' + uniqueValueee + 'AndOrSelection').prop("disabled", false);
```

Using the above code I am able to disable the selection of the dropdown. 
I also want to show a tooltip saying why the dropdown is disabled. For that I have written a function on `@onmouseover = "showToolTip(this.id)"` on my razor dropdownlist.

```
function showToolTip(id)
{
    alert(id);
}
```

If i write the code on other dropdowns which are `enabled` it works fine. But when the disabled dropdown is mose overed, the js function doesn't fire. Plus in chorome i am also not  able to inspect element. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your razor view. I tested it and it is working perfectly for both condition (ddl enabled & disabled):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.City, new SelectList(Model.Lookups.Where(x => x.LookupType == "City"),
    "LookupID", "LookupValue"), "---- Select ----", new { disabled= true, @Title= "Tooltip here" })
```

Please attention to the properties below:

```
new { disabled= true, @Title= "Tooltip here" }
```

Then here is the result with enabled and disabled option:

[image]

Comment: Yildiz : Thanks... it worked. I was trying the same thing but the T of title was small thats why I was getting error. Thanks again

Comment: I am happy that the problem was solved. On the other hand, it is very strange that sometimes similar things can occur and after making uppercase/lovercase the first letter the problem can be solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, HTML disabled elements do not facilitate any JS events like hover, click, etc. For your purpose, you put a `div` overlay with higher `z-index` such that it acts as a disabled area. Then you can define the hover event on the `div` itself.

Comment: Can you share some demo with me. I am new to HTML and stuff. Please